# Why would someone want to attack Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

At 5:03 PM on 27 Feb 2017, according to Twitter, Stack Exchange (specifically Stack Overflow) began to suffer from an attack that turned out to be a DDOS attack, from what I understand:[image]

EDIT: What I really wanted to know was what Stack Exchange *knew* about threats. What kind of people do we *know* have a problem with the sites, and why?

Comment: Very few people conduct attacks for logical reasons other than "because we want to." I mean, there is a so-called Indian Hacker Team that frequently does dumb little things because we refuse to give all the members of their team moderator access. There are people out there that just like causing chaos and nothing more.

Comment: Advertising their botnet, maybe.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev1yL.gif

Comment: @AdamLear: Somehow that is not loading correctly for me. Typo?

Comment: @NathanTuggy No, imgur's been a bit up-and-down for me as well. Reload till it works, I guess? Or try dropping down to http. That fixed some image displays for me earlier, but I've no idea if it was just a coincidence.

Comment: Maybe webcams are sick of looking at us. They don't really have a lot of ways to express themselves, and drawing sparkles and bling on our faces wasn't really getting the message across.

Comment: I am waiting for the day when cars will DDoS Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ShadowWizard a convoy of Uber cabs circling the offices, preventing access?

Comment: Incidently, right now, opening Quora pages results in "*504. Gateway Timeout. Quora is temporarily unavailable. Please wait a few minutes and try again.*"

Comment: @PeterMortensen Quora can be for almost anything. If these are the same people, than they just want to be unhelpful.

Answer (score 30):

It's a mystery. As you can tell from browsing meta for a few minutes, we're universally loved by all of mankind.

Comment: I HATE YOU!  I HATE YOU!  I HATE YOU!.  Also, I have run out of beer:(  Worse, we live miles from the nearest booze shop and I'm too drunk to drive..

Comment: @MartinJames *goes to Area51 to propose Interventions.SE*